# Monitor for resource creation in a region using AWS Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

I was curious if there was a way to have CloudWatch alert if ANY resource is created in a region/AZ?

My use case being I want to only have us-east-2 available for consumption, so I want to get alerted if any resource is created in say, us-west-2.

Googling doesn't really bring me much on this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not Cloudwatch, but rather [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/). With Config, you can build rules to specify how your account resources should look, and then alert if your account violates the specified rules.

The alerts are delivered to an SNS topic, so you can receive them via any method that SNS supports.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a policy to the users roles that only allows them to create resources in a specific region.